# How to sort a query based on another model in Django

Tags: django

If I had:

```
class Assets(models.Model):
    assetMake = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,)
    assetModel = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,)

class Maintenance(models.Model):
    assetID = models.ForeignKey(Assets, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dateRequested = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    dateCompleted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

I want to list all of the assets on a view, and sort them by the last time they were maintained (dateCompleted).

I have been trying to get this working below, but I feel like there is much easier way of accomplishing this, Any help is appreciated

```
class MaintenanceAgeList(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    template_name = 'maintenance_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        maintenanceList = []
        assets = Assets.objects.filter(retire = False)
        today = timezone.now().date()
        for asset in assets:
            maintenance = Maintenance.objects.filter(assetID_id = asset.id, complete =True,).order_by('-dateCompleted')
            if maintenance.count() > 0:
                asset['maintDate'] = (maintenance[0].dateCompleted).date()
                maintenanceList.append(asset)
                asset['days'] = (today - lastMaintenance[0].dateCompleted.date()).days
            else:
                asset['maintDate'] = today - timedelta(days=365)
                asset['days'] = 365
                maintenanceList.append(asset)
        maintenanceList = maintenanceList.sort(key=lambda r: r.maintDate)
        context['items'] = maintenanceList
        return context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
from django.db.models import Max

Assets.objects.annotate(
    last_modified=Max('maintenance__dateCompleted')
).order_by('-last_modified')
```

**Note:** Optionally, you can set the position of *null* values by [`nulls_first` or `nulls_last`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) args.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Arakkal Abu. This may be a separate question , but how could I also count the number of days between now and when the maintenance was completed?

Comment: You can use `annotate()`. As per the SO guidelines, better to ask a new question.